# Why does data in list1 changed automatically when I change the data in the other list2 which is cloned from the list1? Using Vue.Draggable

Tags: vue.js, draggable, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

I am using Vue.Draggable in my Vue project and trying to drag(clone) a button from sider into a draggable component.

I want to modify the data when I clone the button into the component. But I find that when I modify the data in the list which is binded with the component, the original list that sider used got changed automatically.

Is there some kind of synchronization mechanism in Vue.Draggable or something? I want to change the object data in the component only.

I tried to modify the object in the list2 manually by using a vue extension in Chrome browser. And it still happens. So I think maybe it's not bug in my code.

```js
addEntity (conditionID, entity) {
                if (!entity.forChoose) {

                }
                else {
                    let variable = 0;
                    for (let i = 0, len = this.whens.length; i < len; i++) {
                        if (this.whens[i].entity[0].id == entity.id) {
                            variable++;
                        }
                    }
                    this.whens[conditionID].entity[0].forChoose = false;
                    this.whens[conditionID].entity[0].variable = variable;
                    this.whens[conditionID].entity[0].name = entity.name + '-fake';
                }
            },
```

The code above is the event when I drag the data into the component, and changed some variable.

Although I did nothing to the original data in the Sider where I cloned the data from, it still got changed as well.

Is there a way to change the dragged data but do not affect the original data?
Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of the immutability.
so can you try using spread operator to create new shallow copy of your list before you change it.

how to use spread operator (triple dot)

let newArrayOfWhens = [...this.whens]

then use the "newArrayOfWhens" array in your code

You can create a deep clone as well if you want, but try to avoid it if it is not necessary.
you can use a library call "lodash" to do it very easily
[deepClone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Comment: Thank you for answering in detail. I thought of the first way but I found it a little complicated to use. And I've tried looking for answer in the issues of vuedraggable's github repository. The solution that contributor suplied is to re-write the 'clone' function and use deep clone. For example

Comment: clone: function (original) {
                let element = {};
                for (let key in original) {
                    if(original.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        element[key] = original[key]
                    }
                }
                return element;
            },

Comment: I don't know this well so I don't understand why you said I should avoid deep clone if it is not necessary, but it does solve my problem. Thanks for answering again!

Comment: shallow copy: it creates a copy of the main object but does not creates copies for the  sub objects (object can contain another objects) it's keep the reference for other sub objects of the main object. deep clone: it is other way around it creates pure copy of all properties and sub objects of the main object. it allocates separate memory for the new object and it takes time to do that. 
if we are not going to create too many deep clones i think it would be ok. :)